# Social Media share buttons (Facebook,Linkedin,Twitter) with images

Tags: html, share, meta-tags, social-networking

I am using the followings URL for sharing my page on Twitter, Facebook and Linkedin.

```
a href='https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u='+${url}+'&title=Title'
a href='https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='+${url}+'&title=Title&source='
a href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url='+ ${url} +'&hashtags='
```

In my page, there will be many products displayed, and for each product, I need to share it separately. So I need to share images based on the share button of a particular selected product.
For example, if my page has 5 product then we have a total of 5 images(1 image per product), then if a user choose to share the 2nd product then while sharing to social media (Share cards) we need to display the image of 2nd product.
In Pinterest, I have achieved it by using its share URL itself (&media).

```
a href='https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/url='+${url}+'&media='+${imageurl}+'&description='
```

I have tried it with using meta tags. Title, description, URL is correctly populated but images are not displayed properly. I cant use javascript to fill image path because social media crawlers will not validate javascript methods. Is there any way to achieve it by passing the image path along with social media share url.?(Something like I have in Pinterest). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Find solution? I have same issue